# I cannot mount a RAID 10 partition

Tags: debian, raid

A week ago one of my 4 RAID10 disks (4Tb each in a FANTEC QB-35US3R box) died. I changed it and the RAID 10 seems to work (from a hardware point of view). But although I can see dirs and files using testdisk on Debian, I cannot mount it. I get the following message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

dmesg|tail says:

```
[   11.688492] EXT4-fs (sda1): bad geometry: block count 1953480192 exceeds size of device (536870911 blocks)
[  383.777336] EXT4-fs (sda): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  395.620576] EXT4-fs (sda1): bad geometry: block count 1953480192 exceeds size of device (536870911 blocks)
[ 1984.339058] EXT4-fs (sda1): bad geometry: block count 1953480192 exceeds size of device (536870911 blocks)

root@cubox-i:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>

root@cubox-i:~# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 179        0    7822336 mmcblk0
 179        1    7821312 mmcblk0p1
   8        0 7813922816 sda
   8        1 2147483647 sda1
```

**Q:** What configuration have you used for your four disks?

**A:** I am not sure I understand the question.

```
root@cubox-i:~# zgrep CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION=y
```

**Advice** : *Get a newer kernel / better rescue system / proper configuration*

The strange thing (for me) is that **this configuration used to work fine** before one of the disks crashed.

Hint??

```
root@cubox-i:~# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Caution: invalid main GPT header, but valid backup; regenerating main header
from backup!

Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!
Warning! Main partition table CRC mismatch! Loaded backup partition table
instead of main partition table!

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

Found valid MBR and corrupt GPT. Which do you want to use? (Using the
GPT MAY permit recovery of GPT data.)
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT
```

I do not know what to answer... Any suggestion?

**My questions:**

- What does "a new kernel" means? How can I get it?
- What is going wrong?
- What should I do?

François-Xavier

Comment: How did you add the disk? Did you copy the partition schema to the new disk?  What does  `mdadm --query /dev/mdX` or `cat /proc/mdstat`  tell you?

Comment: This is almost certainly a RAID issue rather than a filesystem one. Hardware or software RAID? What configuration have you used for your four disks? Details in the question, please.

Comment: also `cat /proc/partitions` - if you don't have a dedicated hardware raid controller card, you're using the wrong device. In any case the filesystem complains about the device being to small by factor 4, which I hope isn't the case since that'd make it a 4 disk RAID-0, instead of RAID-10, and with a dead drive all data would be gone. Something fishy here...

Comment: @fxtv: Okay, that looks like your kernel lacks support for GPT/EFI partition scheme (`zgrep CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION /proc/config.gz`), causing it to see the fallback 2TB ee msdos partition instead. Get a newer kernel / better rescue system / proper configuration.

Comment: I answered most questions adding information in the original post.